# Use HTTP/2 with JAX-RS client

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jax-rs, http2

I am trying to works with a JAX-RS HTTP/2 server and client. The server side works but I cannot make the client working properly using JAX-RS abstractions. I use Jersey2 JAX-RS implementation and embedded Jetty HTTP server. I also use Jersey proxy client to use directly the API through an interface. The method to construct the client is below.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

(...)
<T> T getClient(int port, Class<T> resourceInterface) {
    return WebResourceFactory.newResource(
            resourceInterface,
            ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .build()
                    .target("https://localhost:" + port)
    );
}
```

Do you have a solution using the same level of abstraction ?

### EDIT

Following the answer from @sbordet, I have implemented a client connector supporting HTTP/2 based on JettyClient. Code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/nhenneaux/jersey-http2-jetty-connector) and artifact is on [image: Maven Central].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey allows to customize the transport using [transport connectors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4895).

There already is a Jersey client transport that uses Jetty's `HttpClient`, but it is configured to use HTTP/1.1, not HTTP/2, see https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/connectors/jetty-connector/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jetty/connector/JettyConnector.java.

I guess that your option would be to either implement a Jersey `ConnectorProvider` and a `Connector` yourself, largely based on those already available, but configuring the HTTP/2 transport as explained in the Jetty [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/http-client-transport.html#_http_2_transport); or ask the Jersey developers to make the creation of the `HttpClient` instance in the existing `JettyConnector` overridable, so that you can customize the `HttpClient` transport with the HTTP/2 one.

Note that if you use HTTP/2 you will need support for ALPN as explained in [this documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/alpn-chapter.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was at this level but the connector is a quite low level api and I am not confident to implement the HTTP/2 version. I thought it should exist something else. I will try to ask the Jersey developers.

Comment: Asking the Jersey developers is probably best; note that the change is trivial, so it should not be much of a problem.

Comment: I have published a Maven artifact using Jetty HTTP client with HTTP/2  transport [com.github.nhenneaux.jersey.jetty.http2:jersey-http2-jetty](https://search.maven.org/search?g:com.github.nhenneaux.jersey.jetty.http2%20AND%20a:jersey-http2-jetty=&core=gav) built from GitHub repository [jersey-http2-jetty-connector](https://github.com/nhenneaux/jersey-http2-jetty-connector).